# Mongoose - Group by array elements, count and sort by count

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have user documents in *users* collection as shown below

```
[
{
_id:"1",
user_name:"abc",
name:"ABC",
following:["xyz"]
},
{
_id:"2",
user_name:"xyz",
name:"XYZ",
following:[]
},
{
_id:"3",
user_name:"pqr",
name:"PQR",
following:["xyz","abc"]
}
]
```

I want to group by *following* attribute, count and then sort - so that I get most followed users' documents as shown below

```
[
{
_id:"2",
user_name:"xyz",
name:"XYZ",
followers_count:2
},
{
_id:"1",
user_name:"abc",
name:"ABC",
followers_count:1
},
{
_id:"3",
user_name:"pqr",
name:"PQR",
followers_count:0
}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.users.aggregate([
                 {$unwind: "$following" },
                 {$group: { _id: "$following","username": {$first:"$user_name"},"name":  {$first:"$name"},followers_count:   { $sum: 1 } }},
                 {$project: {"name":"$name","user_name": "$username", _id:0, followers_count: 1 } },
                 {$sort: { followers_count: 1 } }
])
```

Also,

**UPDATED :**

There is no need to use group by pipeline in your case, you can achive same by

```
db.tests.aggregate([

                {
                  $project : { 
                                user_name:1, 
                                 name :1, 
                                 followingUsers: { $size: "$following" }  
                             }
                },
                {$sort: { followingUsers: 1 } }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Above query gave me the response
[
      {
        "_id": "xyz",
        "followers_count": 2
      },
      {
        "_id": "abc",
        "followers_count": 1
      }
    ]
How can I get other fields of user like name, _id etc?

Comment: Use the above query

Comment: Above updated query gave me `[ 
        {
            "name" : "PQR",
            "followers_count" : 1,
            "user_name" : "pqr"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "ABC",
            "followers_count" : 2,
            "user_name" : "abc"
        }
    ]`
I need name and _id attributes (along with followers_count) of users being followed NOT of followers.

Comment: What do you want.?

Comment: I need most followed users like
`[
{
_id:"2",
user_name:"xyz",
name:"XYZ",
followers_count:2
},
{
_id:"1",
user_name:"abc",
name:"ABC",
followers_count:1
},
{
_id:"3",
user_name:"pqr",
name:"PQR",
followers_count:0
}
]`

Comment: xyz not followed by any user as in your documents, & you have written followers count for xyz 2. can you explain.how.

Comment: For example: _following_ attribute in _pqr_ user represents "_pqr_ is following _xyz_ user and _abc_ user". Like this _abc_ user also follows _xyz_ user. Thus xyz has 2 followers which are _abc_ and _pqr_.

Comment: There is still some misunderstanding.. I need users who are followed more. Not the users who are following more users. Your updated query gave
`[ 
        {
            "_id" : "2",
            "user_name" : "xyz",
            "name" : "XYZ",
            "followingUsers" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "1",
            "user_name" : "abc",
            "name" : "ABC",
            "followingUsers" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "3",
            "user_name" : "pqr",
            "name" : "PQR",
            "followingUsers" : 2
        }
    ]`